# Find real $x$ satisfying $2^x + 2^{|x|} ≥ 2\sqrt{2}$

Tags: functions

Solve for $ x\in \mathbb{R}$ if

$$2^x + 2^{|x|} \ge 2\sqrt{2}$$

The answer is given as $\big(-\infty,\log_{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)\big] \cup \left[\frac 12, \infty\right)$.

Comment: Did you mean $2^x+2^{|x|}\ge2\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I believe the answer should be $\big(-\infty,\log_{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)\big] \cup \left[\frac 12, \infty\right)$

Comment: Split the question into two cases.

Comment: @user84413 yes that's the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If $x\ge 0$, the inequality reduces to $2^x + 2^x \ge 2\sqrt{2}$, while if $x<0$, it becomes $2^x + 2^{-x} \ge 2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I'm getting (√2 + 1) inside the log. How do you get (√2 - 1)?

Comment: Writing $a=2^x$, the second inequality is just $a+\frac{1}{a} \ge 2\sqrt{2}$. Solving for $a$ gives $a\le \sqrt{2}-1$ or $a\ge \sqrt{2}+1$. Since we are assuming $x<0$, the latter is impossible ($\sqrt{2}+1 = 2^x$ implies $x>0$), so $a\le \sqrt{2}-1$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.